# Is there a way to do a "situational" join in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to use SQL to determine how far teams go in the NCAA tournament. I have a database that has 3 tables that I'm using. One table has the results of each game, one has the teams, and one has the rounds based on the day number they take place. Below is the result of running head on the 3 tables:
Results table:

```
  Season DayNum WTeamID WScore LTeamID LScore WLoc  NumOT
   <dbl>  <dbl>   <dbl>  <dbl>   <dbl>  <dbl> <chr> <dbl>
1   1985    136    1116     63    1234     54 N         0
2   1985    136    1120     59    1345     58 N         0
3   1985    136    1207     68    1250     43 N         0
4   1985    136    1229     58    1425     55 N         0
5   1985    136    1242     49    1325     38 N         0
6   1985    136    1246     66    1449     58 N         0

Teams Table:
  TeamID TeamName    FirstD1Season LastD1Season
   <dbl> <chr>               <dbl>        <dbl>
1   1101 Abilene Chr          2014         2019
2   1102 Air Force            1985         2019
3   1103 Akron                1985         2019
4   1104 Alabama              1985         2019
5   1105 Alabama A&M          2000         2019
6   1106 Alabama St           1985         2019

Rounds Table:
 daynum        round
1    134 Play-in Game
2    135 Play-in Game
3    136  Round of 64
4    137  Round of 64
5    138  Round of 32
6    139  Round of 32
```

Using the following code, it's work great for all the teams except for one.

```
    SELECT a.season, b.teamname, c.round
    FROM ncaatourney AS a
    JOIN teams AS b
    ON a.lteamid = b.teamid
    JOIN rounds AS c
    ON a.daynum = c.daynum
```

This gives me the following result:

```
 season   teamname       round
1   1985       Iowa Round of 64
2   1985     Purdue Round of 64
3   1985     Lehigh Round of 64
4   1985        USC Round of 64
5   1985       Ohio Round of 64
6   1985 Washington Round of 64
```

The problem is that this uses when the team's id shows up as the lteamid, which means I don't end up getting the champion. Is there a way to write a CASE statement or IF/ELSE so that it will give me 'Champion' in the round if a teamid shows up in the wteamid column on daynum = 154 (the day of the championship game) but performs the above JOIN otherwise? Or is there a different way to do the JOIN?

Comment: I believe you need to simplify your problem because there are many people on the world who don't know anything about the NCAA its mechanisms (including me). It is not clear to me how the day number or the round or the season should be calculated.

Comment: I guess my question really boils down to that I want to setup a Boolean condition that if it's true, I want to do a JOIN one way and if it's false, I want to do a JOIN another way. 
So if on DayNum 154 the team is listed in the wteamid column of the results table, I want to perform the JOIN in a way that it reads 'Champion' instead of 'Round of 64', 'Round of 32', etc. And otherwise it performs the JOIN I list above.